# Ember.JS Syntax Highlight XML Document

Tags: ember.js, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Ember and Highlight.JS and I want to dynamically edit an XML document and show a syntax highlighted version in a live preview.  Currently I have a preview, but the code is not syntax highlighted.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <p>Name {{input type="text" value=name}}</p>

  Non-Syntax Highlighted output
  <pre>
  &lt;person&gt;
    &lt;name&gt;{{name}}&lt;/name&gt;
  &lt;/person&gt;
  </pre>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="myxmltemplate">
  <person>
    <name>{{name}}</name>
  </person>
</script>
```

[JSBin with this code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sacuy/2/edit?html,js,output)

To get syntax highlighting, I need to render myxmltemplate above to a string, not directly to the page.  This string can be fed into highlightjs to be turned into syntax highlighted HTML.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please note I don't want to put &lt; into my code, I want to be able to maintain an XML template the same way the second one is displayed.  I also don't want to shove the XML into a computed property.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the template gets inserted / rendered after highlight.js has initialized. Therefore you need initialize the highlighting every time the view gets rendered. This can easily be done using the Ember.Views didInsertElement hook.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    // From http://highlightjs.org/usage/ see Custom Initialization
    this.$('pre').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/masomafu/2/edit

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Is it possible to do this with the template below, myxmltemplate?  I'd rather work with < than &gt;